# Chat / Server client Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, client, chat, server

I am currently doing a project for university, I have to create a multiple chat client and server in python 3.4. 
For some reason it will connect to one client but when a second client tries to connect it does nothing. However when the first client disconnects the other client will connect to it. Does anyone have any ideas, I have been trying to work this out for over 3 hours.

**The Client Server**

```
import socket

def Main():
    print("Send 'q' to exit\n")
    address = str(input("ip:port -> "))
    nick = input("nick: ")

    try:
        if address.index(":") != 0:
            host = address[:address.index(":")]
            port = int(address[address.index(":")+1:])
    except ValueError:
        host = address
        port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = input("-> ")

    while message != "q":
        send_message = message + "pPp" + nick
        send_message2 = send_message.encode("UTF-8")
        s.send(bytes(send_message2))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        data_decoded = data.decode("UTF-8")
        data2 = data_decoded
        print(data_decoded)
        messageServer = str(data_decoded[:data_decoded.index("pPp")])
        nickServer = str(data_decoded[data_decoded.index("pPp")+3:])

        if not data_decoded == data2:
            print(nickServer + ": " + messageServer)
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

**The server side:**

```
import socket
import time
import os
from threading import Thread
folderPath = "Chat Logs"
filePath = folderPath + "/" + str(time.strftime("%H-%M-%S_%d-%m-%Y")) + ".txt"
def clientHandler(c):
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        data_decoded = data.decode("UTF-8")
        message = str(data_decoded[:data_decoded.index("pPp")])
        nick = str(data_decoded[data_decoded.index("pPp")+3:])
        print(nick + "$" + message)
        saveChat(nick, message)
        print("   Sending: " + data_decoded)
        c.send(bytes(data_decoded.encode("UTF-8")))
    c.close()
def saveChat(nick, message):
    if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
        os.makedirs(folderPath)
    if not os.path.exists(filePath):
        f = open(filePath, "a")
        f.close()
    f = open(filePath, "a")
    f.write(nick + ": " + message + "\n")
    f.close()
def Main():
    host = str(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    port = 5000
    print(host + ":" + str(port) + "\n")
    Clients = int(input("Clients: "))
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(Clients)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        Thread(target=clientHandler(c)).start()
    s.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: If it is within the scope of your assignment, you could use the [chatserver example from twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/).

Comment: @Robᵩ It isn't I am afraid. Any more ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that in `s.listen(Clients)`, `Clients` is greater than 1? Maybe just force a bigger number...

Comment: @ianribas, Hi there, I do believe that the clients is greater then 1. I am still struggling with it. With "LearningNinja" response the program will send back and to but only once. After that you send out a message but it doesn't arrive. When the other user sends a message out the error message: 
"valueerror: substring not found encoding python"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the `Thread` object correctly. Try one of these:

```
    Thread(target=clientHandler, args=(c,)).start()
```

or

```
    Thread(target=lambda c=c: clientHandler(c)).start()
```

Thread takes a callable as the `target` argument. Instead of passing in a callable, your code invokes the clientHandler, and passes its return value to `Thread.__init__`.

Comment: Hey there, i have tried this and it threw up an error message saying that "args =" is from python version 2.7. I have to use python 3.4 for my assignment. Do you have any more ideas?? Thanks :)

Comment: What, precisely, is the error message? According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#thread-objects), `args` is valid in Python 3.4. Also, I tested the change in Python 3.4.

Comment: @MarkNicholls - I still claim `args` should work, but look at my edit for an alternative.

Comment: I have tried both of them and they both come back with: Cant start new thread error. Any more ideas?

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message? Please copy-and-paste the error message, don't try to retype it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MarkNicholls/Dropbox/Term 2/Python Programming 2/Petes Python/Server.py", line 57, in <module>
    Thread(target=lambda s=s: clientHandler(s)).start()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 745, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread

Comment: That error message doesn't match the program in your question. (Specifically, it invokes `clientHandler(s)` instead of `clientHandler(c)`.) What program are you running?

Comment: I made the change in the server program. Server.py I then opened server.py with python launcher. As per the server program it asked for the number of clients which I put 10. Then the error is displayed.

Comment: The program at this link: http://ideone.com/7QTNEJ works perfectly for me. Does that program generate an error for you?

Comment: I added the bit at the bottom of the from LearningNinja. On the bottom of his code he changed `while True:
    #c, addr = s.accept()
    #print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    Thread(target=clientHandler(s)).start()` 
which turned the S to a C

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! It all works!! Very sorry for being confusing you have been a lot of help. We were confused by mixing peoples replies. Mark :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score -1):

the changed code for server.py works for me. 
what if we accept the connections in the thread handler and pass the socket object as an argument when we call the handler.

```
def clientHandler(s):
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        data_decoded = data.decode("UTF-8")
        message = str(data_decoded[:data_decoded.index("pPp")])
        nick = str(data_decoded[data_decoded.index("pPp")+3:])
        print(nick + "$" + message)
        #saveChat(nick, message)
        print("   Sending: " + data_decoded)
        c.send(bytes(data_decoded.encode("UTF-8")))
    c.close()
```

In main function, I changed the following lines.

```
while True:
    #c, addr = s.accept()
    #print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    Thread(target=clientHandler(s)).start()
```

Here is the connection result:

```
>>> 
10.212.245.81:5000

Clients: 3
Connection from: ('10.212.245.81', 60945)
c1$hi
   Sending: hipPpc1
Connection from: ('10.212.245.81', 60976)
c2$hi
   Sending: hipPpc2
Connection from: ('10.212.245.81', 61096)
c3$hi
   Sending: hipPpc3
```

P.S I didn't try to check the code by exceeding the number of client connect requests.

Comment: Just a curious question, have you done this on a MAC or Windows? Thanks for helping out mate.

Comment: Hello, I have gave it a go, but no luck. when the 1st client sends a message out the server responds but when the 2nd client sends a message back it does't respond. So when the 1st client messages again an error message appears: "valueerror: substring not found encoding python". Any more ideas??

Comment: This answer still has the same flaw as the original -- it invokes `clieantHandler` directly instead of allowing the threading module to invoke it. As it is written, this code (and OP) pass `None` as the target argument to Thread().